# pfSense allow one part of the network access to VPN Tunnel

Tags: vpn, routing, wifi, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

I Have two pfSense routers (Router 1 and Router 2)
ROuter 1 is VPN Server for other routers and  in his LAN network are different servers like domain server, mail server...
Router 2 is WiFI captiv portal. We have one subnet 192.168.1.0/23 and all visitors connected on WiFi can surf on internet.

Is there possibility, and what will be best practise to allow our private laptops to connect to same WiFi and have access to VPN TUnnel and Router 1 and servers?

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hap5e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the tunnel, you will get a new interface, for which you can create custom rules. If no rules are set, pfSense will block any traffic. As such you need to specifically allow certain devices. Create an alias for the VPN network (172.16..) on Router 1, and another one for the allowed clients.

On router 2, under rules, in the tunnel interface, allow traffic from the VPN network to the whitelisted clients. On the LAN interface, allow traffic from the whitelisted clients to the VPN network.